# USB-connected Laser printer (has linux drivers) for printing from Linux and remote systems (Windows and Mobile)?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

Bought a USB-connected monochrome laser printer, after confirming that it has Linux drivers. I understand that once I install the driver and print server (CUPS) on my Ubuntu 20.04 system, this system shall become a printer server. Local and remote clients (other Linux systems) should be able to print to this. Is that right ?

However, would I need to do something specific on my Windows PC, my wife Macbook, few Android phones to be able to print to this print server ? Or would it appear just as a network printer, if they are on the same LAN ? Does CUPS support some printer discovery ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say how/where the printer is attached. My HP Laserjet is connected wirelessly to the network and works across all devices including mobiles. Is it possible to connect your printer to the network router?

Comment: Thanks @User24601, but this is a rather entry-level, USB-only printer (Brother HL-L2321D), with no option to connect to network. I have the printer configured and could print a 2 page document, but nothing after that.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that once I install the driver and print server (CUPS) on my Ubuntu 20.04 system, this system shall become a printer server. Local and remote clients (other Linux systems) should be able to print to this. Is that right ?

Basically - yes. The print server will advertise print queues it has available via DNS-SD. Macs and Androids should discover and show these queues. Dunno about Windows, but I think it can deal with DNS-SD.